# Change value in server

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visualforce-component

currently I have an error at function: yesButton which is:

```
Uncaught Action failed: c:LCC_App_rej_Return_Shipment_c$controller$yesButton [Cannot read property 'Final_Approved__c' of null]
```

My scenario:
I have a button (yes button) where when the user clicks the 'Yes' button, the object field named Final_Approved__c should change to true. However, currently, the datatype of the field is a checkbox with a false value by default.

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApex {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Return_Shipment__c getRSList(Id RSid){
        Return_Shipment__c RSIDList = [Select id, Final_Approved__c From Return_Shipment__c WHERE id =: RSid];
        return RSIDList;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Return_Shipment__c UpdateDataYes(Return_Shipment__c RSIDList) {
        //Change this Final_Approved__c to true
        RSIDList.Final_Approved__c = false;
        update RSIDList; 
        return RSIDList; 
        
    }
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApex" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader"
                extends="c:LCC_GenericLightningComponent"
                access="global">
    
    <aura:set attribute="partially" value="false"></aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="isAdditionalObject" value="false"></aura:set>
    
    <aura:attribute name="queryResult" type="SObject[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="toggleSpinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Return_Shipment__c" type="Return_Shipment__c"/>
    <!--<aura:attribute name="Final_Approved__c" type="boolean" default="false"/>-->
    
    <aura:handler event="c:LCC_GenericApplicationEvent" action="{!c.apexQuery}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>

    <div>
        <div class="slds-scrollable slds-p-around_medium slds-text-heading_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <br/>
            <p>Please confirm if this is FINAL APPROVAL?</p>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleSpinner}">
                <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand" variant="brand">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>                   
                </div>
        </aura:if> 
        
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" variant="brand" disabled="{! empty(v.queryResult)}" onclick="{!c.yesButton}" label="Yes"/>
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" variant="brand" disabled="{! empty(v.queryResult)}" onclick="{!c.afterQuery}" label="No"/>
           
        </footer>
    </div>
    
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    apexQuery : function(component, event, helper) {
        var myQuery = 'SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE processInstance.TargetObjectId=\''+component.get('v.sObjectInfo.Id')+'\'';
        helper.executeQuery(component, event, helper, myQuery);
    },
    
    afterQuery: function(component, event, helper) {
        //after code
        var approvals = component.get('v.queryResult');
        helper.gotoURL(component, '/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=' + approvals[0].Id, '_self');
    },
    
    showSpinner : function(component,event,helper){
        // display spinner when aura:waiting (server waiting)
        component.set("v.toggleSpinner", true);  
    },
    
    hideSpinner : function(component,event,helper){
        // hide when aura:downwaiting
        component.set("v.toggleSpinner", false);
        
    },
    
    yesButton : function(component, event, helper,query) {
        
        var Return_Shipment__c = component.get("v.Return_Shipment__c");
        Return_Shipment__c.Final_Approved__c == false;
        
        
        var action = component.get("c.getRSList");
        action.setParams({
            obj: Return_Shipment__c,
            oId : component.get("v.recordId")  
        });
        // set call back 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert('Updated');
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }    
})
```

May I know how to solve the error? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code for `yesButton()` contains a number of mistakes.

```
    var Return_Shipment__c = component.get("v.Return_Shipment__c");
```

This component attribute is never populated and has no default value, so it is always `null` and following code cannot work.

```
    Return_Shipment__c.Final_Approved__c == false;
```

`==` is a comparison (and in JavaScript, you usually want `===`). `=` is an assignment. You don't actually need either here because your Apex controller method `UpdateDataYes()` assigns the Boolean anyway.

```
    var action = component.get("c.getRSList");
```

This is the wrong action.

```
    action.setParams({
        obj: Return_Shipment__c,
        oId : component.get("v.recordId")  
    });
```

These parameters do not match either of the Apex methods defined in your server-side controller.

---

You don't need to store an sObject instance in your component for this purpose. Just call an Apex method that accepts a record Id, which you already have, and use that to make the update:

```
public static void submitFinalApproval(Id recordId) {
    update new Return_Shipment__c(Id = recordId, Final_Approved__c = true);        
}
```

Comment: +1 Good start, but there's still so many more issues in the question, these changes alone are unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Its look like I need to learn more :-( I will do the changes accordingly, and sure I will ask again here.